# Java 8/Javascript (Nashorn) long interoperatiblity

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

The following Javascript code executed in Java 8 (Nashorn) does not behave as expected :

```
if( a != b )
{
  do_sth();
}
```

a and b are long values coming from Java object (e.g., 1023948, 1023949). For example, when a = 1023949 and b = 1023949, a != b is true.

Note that the following code works fine:

```
if( (a+0) != (b+0) )
{
  do_sth();
}
```

I know about long precision issue (as Javascript numbers are 64 doubles) but I was expecting that "small" long values should work.

Any input is appreciated. Thx.

Comment: I might be missing something but you expect `a == b` to be true when `a` and `b` are `Long` objects with the same `long` value? I don't know what Nashorn is doing here but if in that case `a != b` then it's probably the Java logic being applied, i.e. `new Long(12345) != new Long(12345)` (those are equal but not the same instances).

Comment: You might be right as the issue does not appears with values -128:127. Looks like autoboxing is used...

Comment: See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161665 and  http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/nashorn-dev/2016-August/006439.html for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Nashorn passes the long values as  **JS objects** to the JS side and thus the comparison returns wrong even though the values are same.

You can check with **typeof** *a* and *b* on JS side.